# How to push/pull to GitHub without entering password

Tags: github

I am fairly new to GitHub (2 days only). I created a repository and added two close friends to collaborate. When I push/pull to GitHub using terminal it works perfectly

However, when they try to do it they are asked for a username and password. If they enter their username and password it does not work; but if they enter mine it works.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation "[Inviting collaborators to a personal repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)" includes:

> The user will receive an email inviting them to the repository.
> **Once they accept your invitation, they will have collaborator access to your repository**.

So make sure they have received *and accepted* the invitation.

Otherwise, their credentials would not give them write access to your repository.